# Converting number string to comma version

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a Angular 2 / Typescript  application string that contains number representations such as the following...

> 10000
>
> 10000.50
>
> -10000
>
> -10000.50
>
> 0

I want to add in commas after the thousand mark, for example...

> 10,000
>
> 10,000.50
>
> -10,000
>
> -10,000.50
>
> 0

What is the best way to do this?

I have tried some other answers but nothing is quite right.

For example `this.value.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");` and `this.value.toLocaleString();` don't seem to handle both the comman and decimal point.

Comment: Did you consider using a pipe? https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/CurrencyPipe-pipe.html

Comment: Since you are using Angular2 try using DecimalPipe (either in a view or component/service).

Comment: see this post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript

function numberWithCommas(x) {
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}

Comment: You can also use [NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat/format) with selected locale

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried

```
var some_string_value = '-10000.50';
parseFloat(some_string_value).toLocaleString()
```

?

Answer (score 1):

Use "indexOf('.')",splice to two part,then use the method you found.

```js
function addComma(num){
//some type check here
 var numStr = num.toString();
 var intEnd = numStr.indexOf('.');
var onePart =numStr,otherPart ='';
if(intEnd !== -1){
 var onePart = numStr.slice(0,intEnd); 
 var otherPart = numStr.slice(intEnd); 
}
 
 return onePart.replace(/(\d)(?=(?:\d{3})+$)/g, '$1,')+otherPart;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pipe, you can find a full answer to your question here: [Add Comma Separated Thousands to Number Inputs in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35299583/add-comma-separated-thousands-to-number-inputs-in-angular2)